# How to update index in App Engine Data Store after adding a column?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, database-schema

I'm using Google Cloud datastore. I've added an indexed column to an entity. For the existing entities to show up in a query, the documentation says that all entities need to be saved again.

In a happy world, there'd be a button in the AppEngine console to re-index the column. Apparently, we don't live in a happy world.

Apparently, code needs to be written. What is the best practice for executing this code and making sure that it is only run ones? (I'm using Java. The documentation only seems to have a Phython example that doesn't show how the code is triggered and prevents running a second time.)

Is this something that goes into a ServletContextListener that gets deleted later?

Answer (score 0):

I would use mapreduce. There standard is implementations for Java & Python:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/dataprocessing/

Though using Go would be cheaper: https://github.com/CaptainCodeman/datastore-mapper (*you can also read & save in goroutine asynchronously*)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.

I've never used mapreduce. It seems to take some time to learn a new technology, simply to reindex for a new column. Learning a new programming language (Go) on top of that seems to make a multi-week project out of this.

I ended up creating a servlet and invoking it through the browser.

Comment: Probably it would be useful to create a repo with predefined code so people can just deploy and invoke update through URL parameters (passing kind & filter conditions).

Comment: If you put the code into a separate service, you can write it in a different language if that's easier. For example, you might use the deferred library in Python to put together a quick migrate task if you find existing code. You'd just need to stub out a model in Python and then use something like the examples shown in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred. I'd definitely delete the new service after you're done with it.